# how to replace string newline in javascript or react js .\r\n

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a message from fire back like this "Member Registration Number at row [2,3,4,5] already used. \ r \ nThe phone at row [2,3,4,5] is already used. \ r \ nThe email at row [2,3,4,5] already used. " how to replace the new line with the javascript function? I've tried a number of ways but it hasn't worked

```
message.replace('~(?:\[|(?!\A)\G)[^]\r\n]*\K\R+~', '<br>')
```

the original message is as follows

```
{
     "message": "Member Registration Number at row [2,3,4,5] already used.\\r\\nThe phone at row [2,3,4,5] is already used.\\r\\nThe email at row [2,3,4,5] already used. ",
     "Success": false
}
```

and the results are like this

Nomor Registrasi Anggota at row [2,3,4,5] already used.\r\nThe phone at row [2,3,4,5] already used.\r\nThe email at row [2,3,4,5] already used.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: those aren't newlines.  looks like they've been double escaped.  You need to use \\r and \\n in your regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace` function to do what you want, you just need to adapt the regex. Check the snippet I put for you.

```js
var response = {
  "message": "Member Registration Number at row [2,3,4,5] already used. \\ r \\ nThe phone at row [2,3,4,5] is already used. \\ r \\ nThe email at row [2,3,4,5] already used. Member Registration Number at row [2,3,4,5] already used.\\r\\nThe phone at row [2,3,4,5] is already used.\\r\\nThe email at row [2,3,4,5] already used. ",
  "Success": false
};
var message = response.message
  .replace(/ \\ r \\ n/g,'<br>')
  .replace(/\\r\\n/g,'<br>');
console.log(message);
```

EDIT: You can also chain `replace`, I edit the answer base on you edit

Comment: result like this Nomor Registrasi Anggota at row [2,3,4,5] already used.<br />The phone at row [2,3,4,5] already used.<br />The email at row [2,3,4,5] already used

Comment: you just need to change to what you want in `replace`, in this case `<br>` for `<br />`, that's all

Answer (score 0):

```js
var response = {
  "message": "Member Registration Number at row [2,3,4,5] already used.\\r\\nThe phone at row [2,3,4,5] is already used.\\r\\nThe email at row [2,3,4,5] already used. ",
  "Success": false
};
var message = response.message
  .replace(/\\r|\\n/g,'<br>').replace(/<br><br>/g,"<br>");
  console.log(message);
```

You can you the `.replace` with `regex`